# How to stop a Django View while it is executing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, html, django

I have a Django "view" which does some mathematical operation over large data sets. I takes about 20 seconds(on localserver) for the view to complete the execution.

After the execution, I return a Django template as a response to the request received. I want to know if there is a way I can stop the execution of the view maybe by using another request, or by any other means.

Comment: Stop it while it's running on a browser? Why would you want to stop it?

Comment: So you want to stop the execution of the view from the browser that made the request?

Comment: One reason to stop it would be if it were a Django view serving Ajax calls, say you have a data heavy page, that loads in with ajax, then the user navigates to another page, you'd want to stop the views that serve the ajax calls.

Answer (score 2):

Due to your scenario, you do some `mathematical operations` in your view, so this maybe not user friendly choice, you may wait for a long time to see the response.

The solution is to use [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/) , you can put your time consuming work in the Celery queue, and you can get a quick view response to the frontend, and when the `mathematical operations` done, use the Celery callback to inform frontend the data is ready, and you can send another request or do something else.

Comment: I show two buttons at the frontend, one to generate the report, which in turn call the view that performs those data intensive mathematical operations, and another to cancel that operation. This is necessary to allow users to cancel the operation and change the input they have provided.

So I need a means to stop the execution of the view on click of the "Cancel" button at the frontend.

Comment: I think you can see the Django Signal framework, it's helpful to you.